# Redmine "Internal Error" While adding quotes, Updating and other settings

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-10.04, redmine

I've installed redmine 0.8.7 on a ubuntu 10.04 LTS without any errors.
I can add *issues* to it but, when it comes to update or even create a *quote* i get this error from the server on the browser:

> **Internal error**
>
> *An error occurred on the page you were trying to access. If you continue to experience problems please contact your redMine
>   administrator for assistance.*

and this on the log file:

> *Rendering /opt/redmine-0.8.7/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error*

Comment: Too litle info to help. Did you try to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: yes i know is too little info but is all the info i can get. I can't install a late release because we have been using this one for years. and maybe the databases are changed. The migration is suppose to be slowly

Comment: I don't think so, there must be something before _"500 Internal Server Error"_ message.

Comment: this is a bit of code that comes first:

_/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:752:in `civil'
    /app/models/time_entry.rb:66:in `spent_on='
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2372:in `send'
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2372:in `attributes='
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2371:in `each'
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2371:in `attributes='
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2141:in `initialize'_

Comment: on the fisrt line goes this:

_ArgumentError (invalid date):_

can be because of this?